# add new property with (this) keyword in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, this

in the code below why `this.age = age;` is different from `age = this.age`. the second is undefined.

the code is:

```
 function person(firstname,lastname,age,eyecolor) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    //this.age = age;
     age = this.age; 
    this.eyecolor = eyecolor;
    this.changeName = changeName;
    function changeName(name) {
      // this.lastname = name;
         name = this.lastname;
    }
}
var myMother = new person("Sally","Rally",48,"green");
myMother.changeName("Doe");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
"My mother's last name is " + myMother.lastname;
```

if we change the order `name = this.lastname` the change doesn't happen.

Comment: because `this` has not the property `age`, you need to set it before trying to get it.

Comment: And what is your question? And why did you expect two different things to do the same thing?

Comment: @levi what about the `this.lastname`?

Comment: @FelixKling i thought the assignment operator works both way.my problem is i don't get how they are different.

Comment: You have a constructor function for `person` object that also includes a method function (as object's property).

Comment: The assignment operator always works the same. However, `age` is a variable and `this.age` is a property of the object `this` references.

Comment: Assignment operator evaluates the expression to the right of `=` and assigns the result to the variable on the left of `=`. **It's not symmetrical** (unlike `==`). `a = b` and `b = a` will produce different results in all non-trivial cases.

Comment: @PM77-1 in the second case `this.lastname` was defined outside the function but inside the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you use `this` it refers to the current object's scope. `age` as of that moment is the `age` that's being passed in, but `this.age` was never defined. so you may as well have set `age = undefined`.

`this.age` is part of the object `person()`.
`age` is a value you passed into the object.

```
this.age; //undefined
age=5;//5
this.age;//undefined
age = this.age;// undefined for both
this.age=7;//7
age;//undefined
age=this.age;//both equal 7
```

none of the `this.age` variables are the same in the following example

```
    function bob(){
       this.age;
    }

    function smith(){
       this.age;
       var smithSelf = this;//i just created a value smithSelf that is equal to this inside of smith() so smithSelf is pointing to smith()
       function lastTime(){
          this.age;//this is lastTime() this.age value.
          smithSelf.age;//this is smith() this.age value.
       }
   }
```

given the following a `person(age){}` the `age` that is passed in side the `()` is the value you passed in. `this.age` is not the same as the value `age` that you passed in.

```
function person(age){
   this.age;
}
```

If you are still confused by `this` then you may want to read up on programming scope. all OOP languages have a scope value normally called `this` it refers to "this scope".

Given the example `a=b` you will end up setting `a` to the value of `b`. so if `b` is undefined then `a` will now be undefined. if you want `b` to be equal to `a` then you would do `b=a`. When in an object and you do `this.b` and you pass in the value `a` and lets say `a` is set to `5` if you do `a=this.b` you will notice from the past example that `this.b` was created but you never set a value to it so `this.b` is undefined. So now at this point you set `a` equal to `this.b` so now `a` is undefined.

If you are confused about the order of operations just simply say the equation out loud. `a=b` "A equals B" and then you will understand why the value on the left is set to the value on the right.

Comment: ,thanks for your ansewr but in the second case `this.lastname` was defined outside the function but inside the object

Comment: this is referring to the current object. When you change scope this will mean the scope of the object your in every time. If i have Two object bob and smith both with this.age bobs age and smiths age are not equal.

Comment: ,i just want to check if i get it right.in the code in my question `this.lastname = name;` (this) is for the function chnageName and when we change the order `name = this.lastname;`  there is no this.lastname defined

Comment: `this.lastname` is for the object. `name` is the value being passed in. `this.lastname` must be created before you use it.

Comment: When you create an object it is set to undefined by default. You can then change its value at any time. When you created the object with values this.x this.y the object and all parts of the object are undefined until you set them.